# Delete database tables on theme uninstall?

Tags: themes, database, actions

How can I execute DB queries when theme installs and delete those tables on theme uninstall?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can accomplish it by WP default functionality. Let me explain it.

**1. While switch theme:**

There is a `switch_theme` action that runs right after the theme is switched. switch_theme is triggered when the blog's theme is changed. Specifically, it fires after the theme has been switched but before the next request. Theme developers should use this hook to do things when their theme is deactivated.

```
<?php add_action('switch_theme', 'theme_deactivation_function'); ?>
```

Theme functions attached to this hook are only triggered in the theme being deactivated. To do things when your theme is activated, use `after_switch_theme`.

Delete a theme's options after deactivation:

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
  delete_option('mytheme_enable_features');
  delete_option('mytheme_enable_catalog');
}
```

`switch_theme` will only be called when your theme is *de-activated*.

**2. After switch theme:**

Theme functions attached to this hook are only triggered in the theme (and/or child theme) being activated. To do things when your theme is deactivated, use `switch_theme`.

In other words, the after_setup_theme represents the point at which *WordPress* sets up the current Theme, not the point at which the administrator activates and/or configures the current Theme.

```
<?php add_action("after_switch_theme", "mytheme_do_something"); ?>
```

Add options for your theme and set them to their default values:

```
add_action('after_switch_theme', 'mytheme_setup_options');

function mytheme_setup_options () {
  add_option('mytheme_enable_catalog', 0);
  add_option('mytheme_enable_features', 0);
}
```

`after_switch_theme` only fire when your theme is being activated.

**Referance:** `switch_theme` and `after_switch_theme` actions hook are located in [wp-includes/theme.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/theme.php#L0)

Comment: This is for when you switch your theme. Deleting the theme options when switching to another one is can be a bad user experience since switching themes shouldn't be a destructive action.

Answer (score 0):

Theme activation use [after_switch_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_switch_theme)

```
add_action("after_switch_theme", "setup_db"); 

function setup_db(){
   //run your create table statements
}
```

Theme deactivation use [switch_theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/switch_theme)

```
add_action('switch_theme', 'delete_db_things');

function delete_db_things(){
  //run deletion statements
}
```